# Getting NameError with pytube on error handling line

Tags: python, pytube

I have pytube installed, version 9.5.0. I've needed to include error handling in my download code but instead of this working and passing to the next video, I get the error:

```
    NameError: name 'pytube' is not defined
```

It's referring to line 41:

```
    except pytube.exceptions.VideoUnavailable:
```

My code is as follows:

```
    while j < len(test_fold):
        if len(test_fold[j]) > 6:
            urls2 = url + test_fold[j]

            test_List.append(urls2)
            try:
                yt=YouTube(test_List[j])
            except pytube.exceptions.VideoUnavailable:
                print 'unavailable'
            except pytube.exceptions.RegexMatchError:
                print 'regex error'

            except pytube.exceptions.ExtractError:
                print 'extract error'   
                t=yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, subtype='mp4').all()



                t[0].download('/Volumes/LaCie/folder/test')

            j+=1
```

I tried adding

```
    from pytube import exceptions
```

but this didn't eliminate the error. Any insights on how to solve this so that the error handling works?

Comment: Show complete code including imports.

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 1):

`from pytube import exceptions` won't help you, because you're asking for `pytube.exceptions.VideoUnavailable`. The former means "make the `exceptions` module available", while the latter means "inside the `pytube` module, there is a module called `exceptions`, inside of which is an exception called `VideoUnavailable`". But you never made `pytube` available, just `exceptions`, so you get a `NameError`.

There are two ways to fix what you've got: either `except exceptions.VideoUnavailable`, or `import pytube.exceptions`. The latter is preferred because it's more explicit and avoids namespace conflicts: what if you had another module with an `exceptions` sub-module?